# Aspect-Oriented programming issue in grails . Point-cut methods are not executing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

I am using Grails 2.4.3 . In resource.groovy I have added component-scan

```
xmlns aop:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
context.'component-scan'('base-package': 'com')
```

Then in src/groovy I have created groovy class

```
package com.demo.aspects.mongo.history;

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Aspect
@Component
@Transactional
public class MongoAspectAdvice {
    @After("execution(* com.demo.global.BaseOptionService.save(..))")
    def afterMethod(){
        println "after method execution"
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.demo.global.BaseOptionService.save(..))")
    def beforeMethod(){
        println "before method execution"
    }
}
```

And save funtion in com.demo.global.BaseOptionService is defined as

```
def save(def entity){
        if(entity.id == null){
            entity.createdDate = new Date()
        }
        entity.lastUpdatedDate = new Date()
        log.debug(entity)
        neo4jTemplate.save(entity)
    }
```

And BaseOptionService is extended by UserService in which BaseOptionService method is called.

UserService.groovy

```
         class UserService extends BaseOptionService{

    def addUser(username,email,role,phonenumber){
        log.debug "user ===== "+username
        UserCommand userCommand = new UserCommand()

        userCommand.username = username
        userCommand.email = email
        userCommand.phonenumber = phonenumber
        userCommand.role = role
        if(userCommand.labels?.empty == true || userCommand.labels == null){
            if(role == null){
                userCommand.addLabel(null)
            }else{
            userCommand.addLabel("_USER")
            userCommand.addLabel(role)
            }
        }
        userCommand.isActive = true
        userCommand.token = null

        UserDomain user = userCommand.getUser()
        log.debug "user == "+user
        save(user)
        return user
    }

    def removeLabels(id,label){
        UserDomain user = findOne(id,UserDomain)
        if(user.labels?.contains(label)){
            user.labels.remove(label)
        }
        save(user)
        return user
    }

    def serviceMethod() {

    }
}
```

When save function is executing , I haven't seen println statement of afterMethod and beforeMethod in console and there is no error . I am not sure what wrong I am doing. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your application start, the component scan will scan all packages for check what beans are present.
This process anyway don't instantiate the bean if it's not referenced by any other class. In other way you are telling that yes i have a MongoAspectAdvice class that is annotated with @Component so it's also a singleton but where you use it?
Try to import it in UserService.
Then if stil not working ( for check that you can put a breakpoint in that class ) add the following code to you resources.groovy:

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
mongoAspectAdvice(MongoAspectAdvice) { bean ->
bean.autowire = "byName"
}
```

And then import in your service:

```
def mongoAspectAdvice
```

However you can replicate this behaviour by using some grails ad-hc closures:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    println "Tracing action ${actionUri}"
}
```

And

```
def afterInterceptor = {
    println "Tracing action ${actionUri}"
}
```

Put them in BaseOptionService